# Functional Software Requirement Specification and Project Timeline

Tags: architecture, documentation, requirements

I don't have any experience in writing Requirement specification.

I am writing a new in house web application in .Net and i have been given a document with all the requirments for this new software.

There is a (in house written) time tracking system in use at the moment but i have been asked to redesign it in .Net.

I am the only one in the company with software development experience and as this is internal software so they are not expecting me to write very detail documentation for that.

I have designed the ERD diagram for the database schema, I have also divided the requirements into different sections in the excel sheet and set there priority (L,M,H) and  Phases (1,2,3) for delivery.

My line manager has asked me to define the timeline for this project which is bit difficult as I will be working only 3 days a week on this project and don’t know how long it will take to complete the phase 1 as there are few other projects I am working on.

> **Do I really need to a Requirement Specification document because I have been given one in the word documents (in simple words) or Should I just stick with the one I have designed (divided in different sections). If I do need one then is there any example I can follow?**
>
> **Do i also need a Function specification document? Is it different than Requirement Specification?**
>
> **How do you normally set the timeline for the project? I have just defined the different tasks from database development to software development including and set the roughly days next to them.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Software Requirement specification document (SRS)** mainly act as s an agreement between software vendor and the customer on the required features ,also, it helps in breaking down the requirements into estimable tasks and have good understanding of system requirements.It doesn't have to be a long document it depends on the application size.

As for the documents you already created it can be included in the schedule/Budget section of the document (requirements with priority & rough estimate goes here)& Non-functional requirements (ERD goes here) so you can use both.

**Functional requirements** is a section in the document so if you decided to create an SRS document you'll need it and in some application it is really important to have it.

***Regarding defining a time line - If it were me I'd :***

1-  Define the unknown % in each requirement ( does it need research ? , do I need to try a prototype first ? ..etc) and for this type I'll make it clear to the customer that it need research and will give it a rough estimate [Sometimes the customer changes the priority or cancel the whole feature if the unknown factor 90% for an example)

2- Break down each requirement (known part) into small tasks provided that provided that each task estimate will not exceed 1 day (for an example : create table user , create orm method getuser..etc).

3- Add testing as a separate task (run more than test scenario) & fixing code accordingly.

4- If any documentation is required then it should be added as a separate task as well even if it will take 30 min.

5- Define milestones it is very useful to do feature review sessions with the customer if possible (for an example : milestone one : demo feature 1,2,3) and add the feedback to the tasks log prioritized against remaining tasks. ( you may avoid a lot of re-work if you tried to develop the features in an incremental cycles)

**A couple of links for SRS skeleton**

- http://www.aldex.co.uk/reqspec.html
- http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/how-to-write-a-software-requirements-specification-srs-document.html

Hope it helps